# Extract duplicate JSON tags

Tags: python, json

```
nestedData = """{"dashboardId":8,"evalMatches":[{"value":1,"metric":"newdb.count { creation_date: 2020-11-26 10:29:13 indicator_label: BBP 1H market: ORN/USDT }","tags":{"creation_date":"2020-11-26 10:29:13","indicator_label":"BBP 1H","market":"ORN/USDT"}},{"value":1,"metric":"newdb.count { creation_date: 2020-11-26 10:29:13 indicator_label: STOCHRSI 1H market: UTK/BTC }","tags":{"creation_date":"2020-11-26 10:29:13","indicator_label":"STOCHRSI 1H","market":"UTK/BTC"}},{"value":1,"metric":"newdb.count { creation_date: 2020-11-26 10:29:13 indicator_label: STOCHRSI 4H market: ORN/USDT }","tags":{"creation_date":"2020-11-26 10:29:13","indicator_label":"STOCHRSI 4H","market":"ORN/USDT"}}],"orgId":1,"panelId":14,"ruleId":52,"ruleName":"test alert","ruleUrl":"http://localhost:3000/d/1xBsMrIMk/alert?tab=alert\u0026editPanel=14\u0026orgId=1","state":"alerting","tags":{},"title":"[Alerting] test alert"}"""
```

I'm looking for a way to extract relevant "market" and "indicator_label". I used this code but it only does one extraction step:

```
json_obj = json.loads(cts)
market = (json_obj["evalMatches"][0]["tags"]["market"])
indicator_label = (json_obj["evalMatches"][1]["tags"]["indicator_label"])
creation_date = (json_obj["evalMatches"][0]["tags"]["creation_date"])
```

I need result like this

```
market='ORN/USDT',indicator_label'BBP 1H,STOCHRSI 4H'
market='UTK/USDT',indicator_label'STOCHRSI 1H'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import json
nestedData = """{"dashboardId":8,"evalMatches":[{"value":1,"metric":"newdb.count { creation_date: 2020-11-26 10:29:13 indicator_label: BBP 1H market: ORN/USDT }","tags":{"creation_date":"2020-11-26 10:29:13","indicator_label":"BBP 1H","market":"ORN/USDT"}},{"value":1,"metric":"newdb.count { creation_date: 2020-11-26 10:29:13 indicator_label: STOCHRSI 1H market: UTK/BTC }","tags":{"creation_date":"2020-11-26 10:29:13","indicator_label":"STOCHRSI 1H","market":"UTK/BTC"}},{"value":1,"metric":"newdb.count { creation_date: 2020-11-26 10:29:13 indicator_label: STOCHRSI 4H market: ORN/USDT }","tags":{"creation_date":"2020-11-26 10:29:13","indicator_label":"STOCHRSI 4H","market":"ORN/USDT"}}],"orgId":1,"panelId":14,"ruleId":52,"ruleName":"test alert","ruleUrl":"http://localhost:3000/d/1xBsMrIMk/alert?tab=alert\u0026editPanel=14\u0026orgId=1","state":"alerting","tags":{},"title":"[Alerting] test alert"}"""
data = json.loads(nestedData)

output = {}
for val in data["evalMatches"]:
    if val["tags"]["market"] not in output:
        output[val["tags"]["market"]] = []
    output[val["tags"]["market"]].append(str(val["tags"]["indicator_label"]))

for data in output:
    print("market='" + data + "',indicator_label'" + ",".join(output[data]) + "'" )
```

Output:

```
market='ORN/USDT',indicator_label'BBP 1H,STOCHRSI 4H'
market='UTK/BTC',indicator_label'STOCHRSI 1H'
```

Comment: Not the output asked by @navid

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal: Modified answer